# NSView drawRect method not working?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

**Right now I have two windows.** One of them has an NSView, which acts as a background color and the other one has a colorwell that changes a color variable in a shared instance.

My program sort of works. I can open my colorwell window and select a color, but the background color only updates if I manually resize the window.

I tried to get past this issue by having a thread in the background looping:

```
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
[self updateLayer];
[self display];
```

I'm not completely sure that those 3 lines are necessary, but I am sure that they are re-calling my drawRect method.

I even threw an NSLog into the drawRect method to test. I saw in the console that it was getting called over-and-over again.

Here is my drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{

        [theDATA.main_frame_background_color setFill];
        [NSBezierPath fillRect:dirtyRect];

}
```

`theDATA.main_frame_background_color` is an NSColor from a shared instance. I am positive that the value is changing because my NSView updates when I resize the window.

I'm completely clueless on why this is not working. Hope you can help.

Comment: You should never call `display` method manually. Have you tried `NSRectFill` instead of `[NSBezierPath fillRect:]`? Have you checked if the color is really changed?

Comment: Also, if your view is layer-backed, have you changed it's `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` property to `NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay`? The default value is `NSViewLayerContentsRedrawNever`.

Comment: @Sega-Zero Thanks so much! You don't want to know how long I spent trying to troubleshoot this issue. Setting the `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` was a start. I found out that `setNeedsDisplay` wasn't thread safe for some crazy reason so I used an auxiliary method(as seen in my answer to this question).

Comment: Posted an answer, so you could accept it. Also, if your drawing is just a color fill, you may find useful `CALayer`'s property `backgroundColor` =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to @Sega-Zero's suggestion of using `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` and through a bit of research I found out that I couldn't directly call `setNeedsDisplay` in a thread, so I used `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

My Thread class:

```
- (void)updateLOOP{
    while (true){      

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(refreshClock)
                                   withObject: nil
                                waitUntilDone: NO];

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.1];
        }
    }
}
```

External update method:

```
- (void) refreshClock{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Now everything works as it should. The drawRect method is getting called without having to use `[self display]`.

Comment: Do you really need this thread? Why don't you just use some sort of listening on a value changing - Notification Center, KVO or even array of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

First, never call a `display` method directly. Mark dirty area with `setNeedsDisplay:` and the view will be redrawn after a while. If your view is layer-backed, be aware of `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` property, since it's default value is `NSViewLayerContentsRedrawNever`. There's no way to automatically determine which policy fit your needs best, so this property should be set manually.